# InvalidCOMException in WPF app

Tags: wpf, com, directx

I am getting this InvalidCOMException "COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used". I am using DirectX in my WPF app, Can anyone please tell me what is this error and how can I fix this. Any help be of great value.

Thanks.

Comment: Some code? some XAML ? otherwise we can't really help.

Answer (score 1):

This error generally comes in scenario's when you are referring COM object in your code and while disposing of your application or class. Since no code is supplied so i am assuming this is the same scenario's as described here -

[COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW can not be used - why does it happen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492879/com-object-that-has-been-separated-from-its-underlying-rcw-can-not-be-used-why)

[COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260990/com-object-that-has-been-separated-from-its-underlying-rcw-cannot-be-used)

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/martijnh/archive/2009/12/31/unit-testing-com-object-that-has-been-separated-from-its-underlying-rcw-cannot-be-used.aspx

Generally, comes in case of `STA Apartment State` threading Applications.